# How to show images in field under content type - using Drupal 7

Tags: php, image, drupal, path, drupal-7

I can fetch the image name from database but now I want to show the proper image but I am unable to do that, following is what I have tried:

```
   function _network_drives_array(){

  $query = db_select('network_drive_listing','n');
  $query
    ->fields('n')
    ->orderBy('n.ndlistid');
  $results = $query->execute();

  $array = [];

  foreach($results as $record) {
    $array[$record->public_path] = '<div style="background-image: url(\''.url($record->public_path).'\'); height: 50px; width:50px;background-size: cover;border-radius: 50%;background-position: center;" />'.$record->basename;
  }

  return $array;
}
```

I want to show the proper image but unable to do that, current output I have attached a screen shot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `file_create_url` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7.x instead of `url`

Comment: still not working

Comment: did you use uri like "public://..."  ? only works with uri path

Comment: My path is like this: http://localhost/module_test/product_images/NINA-W101_kombi.jpg

Comment: can you edit in my code where i am wrong?

Comment: can you edit dump $record->public_path value please ?